# Aviso de cerrar app

Tags: android

Estoy trabajando con una app en AndroidStudio.
¿Que código podría implementar para cuando se llame al back para salir de la app me avise si quiero salir o no de ella?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Básicamente tienes que sobrescribir el método `onBackPressed` de la `Activity`:

```
private int backpress = 0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    backpress++;    // La primera vez es 1 (aviso), la segunda es 2 (finish)

   if (backpress > 1) { 
        this.finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pulse de nuevo para salir.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Puedes **resetear** la variable `backpress` para que vuelva a pedir el "pulse de nuevo" pasado X tiempo añadiendo el siguiente código dentro del método `onBackPressed`:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            backpress = 0;                       
        }
    }, 3000);  // Resetea a los 3 segundos
```